# Wie nennt man kurze Sätze, die nur im Zusammenhang mit einem vorher stehenden Satz Sinn ergeben?

Tags: sentence-structure

Gibt es einen Begriff für jene Satztypen, die für sich selbst keinen Sinn machen, sondern nur im Zusammenhang mit einem Satz, auf den sie sich beziehen?

Beispiel: "Sie gab ihm eine Ohrfeige. Mit voller Kraft."

Von welchem Typ sind Sätze wie *Mit voller Kraft*?

Eine Frage an die Grammatikexperten, denn sicher gibt es einen Ausdruck dafür, aber er lässt sich nicht von mir irgendwie nicht ergoogeln. [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_%28Grammatik%29) liefert einige Beispiele für Satztypen, aber just dieser scheint nicht darunter zu sein. Es handelt sich hier nicht um [Ellipsen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_%28Sprache%29) - oder doch?

Comment: Das ist gar kein Satz, denn ein Satz besteht aus einem Subjekt und einem Prädikat.

Comment: @Em1: Lt. Wikipedia herrscht alles andere als Einigkeit darüber, was ein Satz ist und was nicht - so habe ich das verstanden. In jedem Fall, Satz oder nicht, bleibt die Frage: wie nennt man so ein Ding?

Comment: Dein Wiki-Artikel sagt unter "unvollständiger Satz": das (Satz)-Fragment, eine Erscheinung verstümmelter Texte. --- Ich glaub, das passt.

Comment: Man *könnte* dies als Ellipse auffassen. "Sie gab ihm eine Ohrfeige. (Sie tat dies) mit voller Kraft." Ich fühle mich dabei aber nicht ganz wohl, da hier nicht einfach eine weitere Aussage um wiederholte Elemente verkürzt wird, sondern vielmehr eine pointierte Betonung erreicht werden soll gegenüber einem einfachen "Sie gab ihm eine Ohrfeige mit voller Kraft". Gibt es vielleicht einen Begriff über Ellipse hinaus, der diese Betonung mit umfasst? Der Punkt würde gesprochen wohl eher als Sprechpause daher kommen: "Sie gab ihm eine Ohrfeige - mit voller Kraft!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Das ist eine Ellipse**

Das ist kein grammatikalisch vollständiger Satz, sondern nur ein Satz-Fragment. Um als "ganzer Satz" durchgehen zu können, braucht eine Folge von Wörtern ein Subjekt und ein Prädikat. Alles andere ist optionales Beiwerk. Die Wörter "Mit voller Kraft" enthalten weder ein Subjekt (das im Nominativ stehen müsste) noch ein Prädikat (das ein Verb enthalten müsste). Sie sind in Wahrheit einfach nur eine Beifügung zum Prädikat des vorangehenden Satzes:

> Sie gab ihm mit voller Kraft eine Ohrfeige.

Wenn du möchtest, kannst du dieses Fragment aber als Ellipse ansehen. Ellipsen sind Fragmente, denen wesentliche Elemente eines Satzes fehlen. Beispiele sind:

> Alles Walzer!
>   Wer da?

Dass das von dir genannte Fragment erst in einem größeren Kontext, also mit einem Vorläufer-Satz, einen Sinn ergibt, ist meines Wissens kein Kriterium für irgendwelche benannten grammatikalischen Konstrukte.

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass es eine Ellipse ist. Vllt ist meine Ansicht etwas zu streng, aber eine Ellipse imho muss vervollständigt werden können, ohne weitere Informationen zu erhalten. Wenn ich nur "Mit voller Kraft" sage, dann benötigt es aber weitere Informationen, um den ganzen Satz zu rekonstruieren. Anders aber "Ich fahre nach Berlin, du nach München". Hier benötigt es keine weiteren Informationen um den Satz zu vervollständigen. In OP's Beispiel ist der erste Satz aber eine weitere Information, damit der zweite unvollständige Satz aufgefüllt werden kann.

Comment: @Em1: Ich gebe zu, dass man darüber begründermaßen auch anderer Meinung sein kann. Da sich aber für beide Standpunke Begründungen finden lassen, die dann von der jeweiligen Gegen-Partei leicht durch neue Begründungen entkräftet werden können, könnte sich daran eine lange und fruchtlose Diskussion entfachen, zu der ich aber keine Lust habe.

Comment: Dann sei es eine Ellipse...

Answer (score 3):

Meine erste Vermutung war ein *Fragment*, aber weitere Recherche brachte mich auf den **[Nominalsatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalsatz)**:

> Unter **Nominalsatz** werden zwei verschiedene Dinge verstanden:
>
> - ein Satz, dessen Prädikat aus dem Hilfsverb sein (Kopula) und einem Prädikatsnomen besteht [...].
> - ein Satz, der kein Verb als Prädikat enthält.[2](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_%28Grammatik%29#Unvollst.C3.A4ndiger_Satz)
>
> Im Sinne der letzten Definition bestimmt Tesnière aufgrund des Zentrums eines Satzes neben Verbalsätzen auch Nominalsätze. Hierbei handelt es sich um Substantivsätze („Tor!“), Adjektivsätze („Schön.“), Adverbsätze („Hierher.“).[3] Zu ergänzen sind Partikelsätze („Ach.“, „Ja.“).

Im Sinne dieser Definition also konkret ein **Adverbsatz**.

Siehe dazu auch eine [kurze Gegenüberstellung von unvollständigen Sätzen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_%28Grammatik%29#Unvollst.C3.A4ndiger_Satz).

Answer (score 2):

### [Epiphrase](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphrase)

Es handelt sich hier eher um ein stilistisches als ein grammatikalisches Phänomen -- denn es ist ziemlich klar, dass der Nachtrag ein nur durch Interpunktion oder Betonung abgegrenzter Teil des vorhergehenden Satzes ist, wobei sich der Bezug nicht aus grammatikalischen Regeln ergibt, sondern vom Rezipienten aus dem Zusammenhang erschlossen werden muss. Einen solchen stilistisch abgegrenzten Nachtrag nennt man *Epiphrase*.

Eine Ellipse ist das nicht, denn es wird kein Satzteil weggelassen, lediglich abgegrenzt bzw. hinzugefügt. Weder dem ersten Satz 'fehlt' etwas, denn er ist syntaktisch vollständig, noch dem Nachtrag, denn man würde den Satz ja normalerweise nicht zweimal hintereinander reihen. Vielmehr ist auch das Hinzugefügte als solches in sich vollständig.

Answer (score 0):

Phrase:
zusammengehöriger Teil eines Satzes; aus mehreren, eine Einheit bildenden Wörtern, auch aus einem einzelnen Wort bestehender Satzteil; Satzglied

Comment: Hey Florin. Willkommen auf German SE. Wenn du noch eine Quelle angibst und vielleicht noch einen Satz dazu schreibst, könnte das eine recht gute Antwort werden. Im Moment sieht es noch etwas lieblos hingeworfen aus. ;)